# add multiple multi string values to registry using array

Tags: vbscript

Code is cleaned and changed from previous post since old logics had various errors that have been corrected and narrowed down to one error in one condition that I cant find an answer to. Currently getting error when my url is being read as only value and throwing Subscript Out of range error even though array is initialized. Other conditions when user has preset items or no key at all works perfectly. Thanks.

```
option explicit
    'on error resume next
    Dim ObjName,oADSysInfo,strComputer
    Dim objReg,IE_Main,mstrValName,strFunctionIntranet,strNYHomepage,multiStringValues(),allURLs(),itemname,a,return
    Set oADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
    Set ObjName = GetObject("LDAP://" & oADSysInfo.UserName)
    strComputer = "."
    Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
    Const HKCU = &H80000001
    IE_Main = "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main"
    mstrValName = "Secondary Start Pages"

    strNYHomepage = "http://www.google.com"
    strFunctionIntranet = "www.mycompany.com"

    SetHomePage

    Sub SetHomepage

            objReg.setStringValue HKCU,IE_Main,"Start Page",strNYHomepage

            'Reading MultiStringValue of "Secondary Start Pages" for HKCU and continuing if it has something preset.
            return = objReg.getMultiStringValue (HKCU,IE_Main,mstrValName,multiStringValues)

            If return=0 Then
                        a=0
                        'Reading all items currently set to make sure users retain their existing URLs.
                        For Each itemname In multiStringValues

                        'Only continue if any of the existing URLs DO NOT MATCH what we are enforcing as the URL.
                            If itemname <> strFunctionIntranet Then
                                WScript.Echo itemname               
                                WScript.Echo "itemname is NOT equal intranet"
                                a = a + 1
                                ReDim Preserve allURLs(a)
                                allURLs(a) = itemname
                                'a = a + 1
                            End If      
                        Next

                        objReg.DeleteValue HKCU,IE_Main,mstrValName
                        'Enforce our URL to always be the first item.
                        allURLs(0)=strFunctionIntranet

                        'Set the new MultiStringValue registry key back.
                        objReg.setMultiStringValue HKCU,IE_Main,mstrValName,allURLs
                        WScript.echo "finished setting all secondary tabs... "

            Else

                strFunctionIntranet = Array(strFunctionIntranet)
                objReg.setMultiStringValue HKCU,IE_Main,mstrValName,strFunctionIntranet                     

            End If

    End Sub
Wscript.Quit
```

Comment: You can't use `Array()` on the left side of an assignment. Besides, `allURLs` already is an array, so why the `Split` anyway?

Comment: Hi Ansgar, Actually I had taken out the Array(allURLs) and ReDim above it, still the type mismatch error. Please help. Thanks for looking up and responding to my question so quickly.

Comment: Please show the exact error message and line that raises it. According to your code you should be getting an "invalid parameter" error.

Comment: Ok. Can you pls identify where and what can be changed to correct the type mismatch or invalid parameter error as it is in this code? Ill send more info when in office shortly. Thanks much.

Comment: objReg.setMultiStringValue HKCU,IE_Main,mstrValName,allURLs is generating the Generic failure. Error reads: SWbemObjectEx (31,6) : Generic failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array contains an empty element, because you create it [one field too big](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Change this line:

```
ReDim Preserve allURLs(a+1)
```

into this:

```
ReDim Preserve allURLs(a)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have modified the code to make it more readable and changing what you have provided as well, yet another error in one condition but other conditions work fine. I have updated the code above with new logic. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't realise there was another question about this, have expanded on the problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37142455/692942).